# mysql insert problems and comparing

Tags: android, mysql

Hi guys after searching for 2-3 days,i have totally no clue as to what is wrong so i appreciate some help :)

I am using wampserver..what i am having problem is inseting data into mysql from android ..whenever i press the insert button,a blank row is added to my columns without any information.

This is my php for inserting

```
<?php
$abc=$_POST['abc'];
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if (!$con)

{

die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

}

mysql_select_db("dbinsert", $con);
$sql="INSERT INTO Detail (Utext) VALUES ('".$abc."')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))

{

die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

}

echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con)

?>
```

for my android

```
  package com.project.insert;

  import java.util.ArrayList;

  import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;

  import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;

  import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;

  import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;

  import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;

  import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;

  import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

  import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;



  import android.app.Activity;

  import android.os.Bundle;

  import android.util.Log;

  import android.view.View;

  import android.widget.Button;

  import android.widget.EditText;



  public class PassData extends Activity {

      /** Called when the activity is first created. */

      @Override  

      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          setContentView(R.layout.main);





          Button Insert=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

          Insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

          public void onClick(View v)

          {      

          try          

               {  

                  EditText CompleteText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

                  ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("abc", "'"+CompleteText.getText().toString()+"'"));

                       Log.e(""+CompleteText.getText().toString(),"0");    

                       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                       HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/InsertStatement.php");

                       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);



               }  

               catch(Exception e)

               {

                       Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());

               }

          }

      });

      }

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see where you do anything with `nameValuePairs` to put it into the request.

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/InsertStatement.php");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

might do the trick.

For security reasons, you might want to add the `'` on the server (and **not** the android code - right now you use both which would show a mysql error) and use `mysql_real_escape_string` server-side.

Comment: hi thx for the answer but when i put                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
now whenever i insert,even a blank row is not added..it seems like nothing at all is inserted into the db

Comment: Did you remove the `'` in the client app? Have you tried outputting the response by the mysql server (if it says `Error: ...` or `1 record added`? Printing `$sql` could also be worth a try to spot what's wrong.